# How to delete a QPushButton that were added in another function in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I’m trying to write a GUI application which will add a 'Delete' button when you press the 'Clear' button, and 'Clear' must turn to 'Add'. The 'Delete' button should be added to a QHBoxLayout and then when you press 'Add' - it will delete the 'Delete' button from the QHBoxLayout.
Ive tried finding the button ive added and using deleteLater() on it - but it gives me a run time error (the type which i get is QWidget and not QPushButton).

Ive tried casting the item to QPushButton and then using deleteLater() - still doesnt work.

Any help is welcome.

```
    def add_image(self, button_index):
    try:
        file_path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open Image', '*.jpg')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        self.status_bar.showMessage('The path {} is not valid'.format(file_path))
    else:
        if file_path[0] != '':

            new_image=QPixmap(file_path[0]).scaled(self.image_height,self.image_width)

            self.image_label_list[button_index].setPixmap(new_image)
            self.button_list[button_index].setText('Remove')
            self.status_bar.showMessage(
                'Image {} was added successfully!'.format(get_name_from_path(file_path[0]))
            )

            if self.button_layout_list[button_index].count() > 1:
                delete_button = type(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton)(self.button_layout_list[button_index].itemAt(1))



                delete_button.deleteLater()

                self.button_layout_list[button_index].removeWidget(self.button_layout_list[button_index].itemAt(1))
                print('number of items: {}'.format(self.button_layout_list[button_index].count()))

            if (button_index - (len(self.button_list) - 1)) == 0:
                empty_image_layout = QVBoxLayout()
                button_box_layout = QHBoxLayout()

                empty_pic_label = QLabel()
                empty_pic = QPixmap('empty p.png').scaled(self.image_height, self.image_width)
                empty_pic_label.setPixmap(empty_pic)

                add_button = QPushButton('Add')
                # add_button.setFixedWidth(self.image_width)
                add_button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
                button_box_layout.addWidget(add_button)

                empty_image_layout.addWidget(empty_pic_label)
                empty_image_layout.addLayout(button_box_layout)

                item = self.image_box.itemAt(self.stretch_index)

                self.image_box.removeItem(item)
                self.image_box.addLayout(empty_image_layout)
                self.image_box.addStretch()
                self.stretch_index += 1

                # Book keeping
                self.image_layout_list.append(empty_image_layout)
                self.button_layout_list.append(button_box_layout)
                self.image_label_list.append(empty_pic_label)
                self.button_list.append(add_button)

def remove_image(self, button_id, button_index):
    image_label = self.image_label_list[button_index]
    image_label.setPixmap(self.empty_pic)
    button_id.setText('Add')
    delete_button = QPushButton('Delete')
    print(type(delete_button))
    print(self.button_layout_list[button_index].count())
    self.button_layout_list[button_index].addWidget(delete_button)
```

Comment: This might not be the best answer, but I would create both buttons, set  `delete_button.hide()` on init and then `delete_button.show()` and `add_button.hide()` when needed.  Alternatively, try to find the button with the children property of QObjects: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys    
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *

class Window(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(500, 100, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle("PushButton - `Clear` -> `Add` + `Delete`")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('E:\\_Qt\\img\\qt-logo.png'))

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.btn    = QPushButton("Clear")  
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.buttonPress)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.btnDelete = QPushButton("Delete")  
        self.btnDelete.clicked.connect(self.buttonDelete)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

    def buttonPress(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        if sender.text() == "Clear":
            self.btn.setText("Add")
            self.layout.addWidget(self.btnDelete)
            self.btnDelete.show()
        elif sender.text() == "Add":
            print("sender - self.btn", sender.text())
            self.btnDelete.hide()
            self.btn.setText("Clear")

    def buttonDelete(self):
        print("You pressed the button `{}`".format(self.sender().text()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = Window()
    #test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It was really helpful!